# Uwsgi Nginx long urls are failed with out any error message

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Configured the UWSGI configuration in supervisor and Nginx. The length of the URL is 5076 characters. It is working fine on sample port. The request is passed Nginx and then came to the supervisor. It returns the following message

```
generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 4 headers in 132 bytes (1 switches on core 58)
```

This is my supervisor uwsgi command

`[program:web]
 command=uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:1665 --master --module web.wsgi --chdir dir_name --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings --processes 32 --threads 100 --max-requests=5000 --listen 65535 --vacuum -b 32768
redirect_stderr=true
autorestart=true`

Comment: Can you show your configuration?

Comment: `[program:web] command=uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:1665 --master --module web.wsgi --chdir dir_name --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings --processes 32 --threads 100 --max-requests=5000 --listen 65535 --vacuum -b 32768 redirect_stderr=true autorestart=true`

Comment: Format the example in your question. It will make it easier to read. Edit the question then highlight the example and click on the code formatting `{}` button

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Updated the question.